# What is difference between read and read_file in configparser in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I am wondering what is difference in usage of read and read_file in configparser. As far as I have tested

```
config_parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
config_parser.read(config_file)
```

and

```
config_parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
config_parser.read_file(config_file)
```

both works for me. 
config_file is name of my config_file I am passing as input parameter.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read "read: Attempt to read and parse a list of filenames, returning a list of filenames which were successfully parsed.", "read_file: Read and parse configuration data from f which must be an iterable yielding Unicode strings (for example files opened in text mode)."

Answer (score 7):

`read_file` accepts a file-like object, `read` accepts a file *name*.

The main issue with `read` is that if the file doesn't exist, it fails silently, leaving the `ConfigParser` empty.

```
config_parser.read("config.ini")  # object is unchanged even if file doesn't exist
```

That cannot happen with `read_file` since you control the way the file is opened.

```
with open("config.ini") as f:
   config_parser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
   config_parser.read_file(f)
```

The other useful case is when you have a list of lines representing a `.ini` file contents.

`read_file` kind of "acccepts" a string as input (since strings are iterable) but the result isn't useful:

```
>>> config_parser.read_file("config.ini")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "L:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 690, in read_file
    self._read(f, source)
  File "L:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 1057, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: '<???>', line: 1
```